# Meaning of the 'magic circle' quote

Tags: analysis, dialogue, through-a-glass-darkly

Can you explain the meaning of the following quote from Ingmar Bergman's [Through a Glass Darkly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055499/)?

> We draw a magic circle around ourselves to shut out everything that doesn’t fit our secret games. Each time life breaks through the circle, the games become puny and ridiculous, so we draw a new circle and build new defences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wicca, it is common to [draw a protective circle](http://wiccanspells.info/learn-wicca-basics/casting-a-circle-protection/) on the ground inside which to conduct some ritual.  The purpose is to prevent the distractions of the outside world from breaking the concentration of those within.

Although I don't believe the film is suggesting that any sort of magic is being practised, the circle of protection is used as a metaphor for the mental walls created by Karin in her slow retreat from reality.

Answer (score 2):

David(father) is talking about himself. He was happy about recognition of his book when his wife died. He fled when he found out his daughter was ill. He limited himself to a magic circle, i.e. his so-called art. But his art is not genuine. It is just a escape to avoid unpleasant situation. This quote also can explain some people's behavior toward hard conditions.